# How do I file a bug report with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-data

I can't manage to find a way to file a bug report.
I just want to report a mistake in the current Spring Data documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigate to site: https://jira.spring.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa
Click on Sign Up for an account link and register. Login again and then choose appropriate project and raise your bug report.

Comment: could you please update your (accpted) Answer - it was right in 2014 but Spring has changed and issue reports should be reported via Github Issue tracker (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues). - more details about how to report a bug can be found in "Contributing to the Spring Framework" https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md - one important point, some subprojects like "Spring Data Jpa" use other issue tracker - check there GitHub readme

Answer (score 11):

As of 2019, use https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues

The Spring Framework has migrated its entire history of issues from Jira to GitHub. See this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/15/spring-framework-s-migration-from-jira-to-github-issues) for details.