# spring boot throw OutOfMemoryError:PermGen space when using velocity-tools

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity

when using spring-boot, it throw OutOfMemoryError:PermGen space.
the stacktrace is like:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:219)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.view.velocity.EmbeddedVelocityToolboxView.getToolboxConfigFileAwareServletContext(EmbeddedVelocityToolboxView.java:73) 
  ...
```

I read the source code at EmbeddedVelocityToolboxView.getToolboxConfigFileAwareServletContext:

```
    private ServletContext getToolboxConfigFileAwareServletContext() {
        ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
        factory.setTarget(getServletContext());
        factory.addAdvice(new GetResourceMethodInterceptor(getToolboxConfigLocation()));
        return (ServletContext) factory.getProxy(getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
```

after debugged it, I found that every time spring-boot generate a velocity view, this method will be called, and a new java class will be created. so after a few minutes, it will throw OutOfMemoryError:PermGen space.

This appears to be a bug in spring boot. I can't find somewhere to report bugs in spring boot website, so I wrote it here. can somebody help me please.

Comment: Do you want help to fix it, or help to report the bug?

Comment: I have fixed it, so I want help to report the bug.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558004/how-do-i-file-a-bug-report-with-spring

Comment: Thanks, I found this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues

Comment: I found solution to this bug, The bug appears in spring-boot 1.2.*.RELEASE，Use 1.3.* or higner will resolve this.